# Brownian motion & strong markov property

Tags: integration, brownian-motion, stopping-times

[image]

I got these equations (8.3 and 8.4) from the book Introduction to Stochastic processes with R by Dobrow. I cannot for the life of me understand how eq. 8.3 turns into 8.4 by popping out the t variable and changing the lower integration limit to $a/ \sqrt{t}$. As t is both in the denominator as $\sqrt{t}$ and in the exponential as $1/t$..

I tried to find an explanation online but to no avail, anyone that can shed light on this mysterious change of integration limits?

Comment: $sqrt(x^2) = abs(x)$

Comment: Okay yeah.. that takes care of the exponential but how about the denominator?

Comment: They used the substitution $y=\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{t}}$, which gives $\sqrt{t} \mathrm{d}y=\mathrm{d}x$, and the change of limits. The $y$ in $\mathrm{d}y$ is just a dummy variable, which they relabel to $x$.